# jQuery tmplItem.update() clears nested template data?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-templates

I have a parent template with a nested template. When I select and change a tmplItem value from the parent template and call .update(), it seems to clear all data from the nested template?

Crude example paste here: http://pastebin.com/cjDKmmyU

Comment: I have the same problem. I have a template building a div and inside there is a textbox, my textbox's text is clearing after I call update. (The value of the textbox is not binded to anything by the template)

Comment: Are you serious? The code you provided... <div class="stuff"></div> is empty to being with and none of the code you gave puts anything in the div.stuff element - try again and this time give us a running example on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to update your template element data attribute value with lodash.

```
// $this is your template element
_.set($this.data(), 'tmplItem.data.value', 'new value');
```

Then get your template element value from that data attribute with lodash. For example,

```
_.get($this.data(), 'tmplItem.data.value');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working sample based on your paste: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/pK8ye/

Is there something different that you are doing in your project?